# How to wait for an observable to complete?

Tags: .net, f#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

In Node.js, you can set up a server and the process won't terminate as long as the server is alive and active in the event loop. I am wondering if it would be possible to do something like that using reactive extensions? I know how to set up a named pipe and make use of it to communicate with the Node server in another process, but I am not sure how to keep the program from terminating via anything other than waiting for a keypress. I'd like to implement that server as a part of a reactive pipeline. Would it be possible to block the main thread until the pipeline completes?

Comment: I have written a small library for C# and F# which abstracts the lifetime of another process as an observable, through the standard in/out. It's useful for managing/composing server processes. See  https://github.com/deviousasti/stdio-rx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ml
open System
open System.Threading
open FSharp.Control.Reactive

module Observable = 
    /// Blocks the thread until the observable completes. 
    let waitUnit on_next (o : IObservable<_>) =
        use t = new ManualResetEventSlim()
        use __ = Observable.subscribeWithCompletion on_next (fun _ -> t.Set()) o
        t.Wait()

Observable.interval (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
|> Observable.take 3
|> Observable.waitUnit (printfn "%i...")

printfn "Done."
```

The above is using the [F# Rx bindings](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive), but the C# version would be similar. The library itself has `Observable.wait` which is of type `IObservable<'a> -> 'a`, but that one has the disadvantage of throwing an exception on empty sequences and keeping the latest value in memory until the observable is disposed. This one has the right semantics if the final value is not important.

I've looked under the hood and `wait` uses `ManualResetEventSlim` to block the thread it is on, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but I can't give an answer in F#, but in C# this is quite simple.

If I had this example:

```
Observable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

...and I wanted to wait until it completed, I could rewrite it like this:

```
    Observable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
        .ToArray()
        .Wait();
```

...or:

```
    await Observable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
        .ToArray();
```

As Marko pointed out in the comments, this approach creates an array that may be quite large. To combat this you can replace `.ToArray()` with `.LastAsync()` (which was named before the general use of `Async` to indicate a `Task` - in this case it just returns the last element of the observable as a `IObservable<T>`).

The `.Wait()` does throw on an empty observable, but the `await` version does not.

Comment: Both your and @Asti's answer have the problem that they enqueue all the values before taking the last one out. Your answer in particular has the extra problem of throwing an exception on empty sequences. I don't think converting to an array does anything here except waste memory. I won't downvote your answer as I am in a good mood, but I wish I hadn't upvoted Asti's answer.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic - Thank you for the feedback. I've hopefully addressed both concerns in my answer now.

Comment: `.LastAsync()` will also throw an exception on an empty sequence.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic - Yes, but I didn't say it didn't. The `await` version works with `.ToArray()`.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Since it was your earnest wish, I have deleted my answer.